# Xamarin.Forms iOS app compilation for remote certification

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, apple-developer-account

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to compile the iOS app in Visual Studio if I don't have Apple Developer License.
A compiled app will be sent for signing by the organization's management and returned back for test on actual device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is an Ad-Hoc build. To answer your question - no, it is not possible to do so without a distribution certificate & Ad-Hoc provisioning profile. You can read more about the configuration in [Manual provisioning for Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning) & [Device provisioning for Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/)